# C++ Windows API WebKit

Tags: c++, winapi, webkit

Как собрать C++ Windows API Desktop приложение с [WebKit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)? Видел WebKit .NET но интересует чисто C++

Comment: В общем случае проблема решается путем вбивания хорошего поискового запроса типа [C++ WebKit integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311435/how-do-i-embed-webkit-in-a-window) - первая ссылка. + Есть ещё QWebKit и разные chromiumebmeded решения, осталось загуглить.

Comment: QWebKit не подходит

Comment: По ссылке все есть.